# Why doesn't x86 assembly have a standard

Tags: assembly, x86

Why isn't there a standard for the x86( or any other ) assembly programming language. For example the C programming language was standardized by the ANSI.

This could make it so there isn't so many different assemblers

Comment: Here is a similiar question. You may read the answers there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065026/assembly-language-standard

Answer (score 2):

Assembler language is just CPU instructions, for readability replaced with abbreviated commands.

Every CPU architecture is different, and has different instructions - x86 code will not run on ARM or on MIPS CPU, same architecture may have several revisions and features (SSE, MMX, NEON etc).

So an assembler for different architecture will have different instructions, there's no way to standardize that. The only thing you can probably standardize is MOV instruction between memory and register, however if you want speed, you'll use all incompatible tricks that your architecture provides, such as SSE to move regions of memory in bulk.

x86 architecture is so popular that it has two different standards for assembler language - NASM and GNU assembler (gas), other architectures usually only have GNU assembler.

Comment: you misunderstood my question I'm not talking about different architectures i'm pacifically talking about x86 and it's different variants (For Example CS216)

Comment: The X86 assemblers are similar except for the GNU type assemblers. I'm not sure why GNU assembler is different than the Intel / Microsoft / Masm / Nasm / Tasm / ML / ... assemblers. My guess is that the GNU assembler for X86 was a minimal effort port of an exsisting GNU assembler for a different processor.

Comment: I have to confess as to some bafflement when I encountered x86 after numerous others. Assembly languages tend to have either Load this from here or Store this here. x86 (as defined by Intel) had "move into here, this" which didn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. Maybe that initial Yoda-esque definition opened the doors to some non-standard rationalization.