# Assembly language syntax standard

Tags: assembly, syntax, nasm, masm

Why assembly language **differs in syntax** even for the same Operating system and Instruction set? For example **NASM** have **different syntax** than **MASM** for windows. why isn't there any standard for the syntax?

Comment: Because the authors didn't like the existing ones and thought they had the only correct idea about how the syntax should look.

Comment: [There is a standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8073217), it's just that nobody uses it.  :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly language standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065026/assembly-language-standard)

Comment: Same reason we have different, incompatible, operating systems that run on the same hardware.  Personal choice.  Even with things like C++ (something with a standard) compilers they try to conform but they add their own, incompatible, features to distinguish them from competitors for whatever reason (usability, marketing/sales, intentional incompatibility).

Comment: @BoPersson : If you go the the link for that standard (*694-1985 IEEE standard*), it is now listed as `withdrawn standard`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the same reason there are multiple Unix shells (bash, zsh, dash, Solaris's non-POSIX-sh `/bin/sh`, etc. etc.): Someone decided to make a new implementation of the language (or a mostly-compatible one) because they didn't like something about the existing language or its specific implementation.  (Other than features, reasons can include: old implementation was non-Free, not portable to a platform they wanted, slow, etc.)

This would be a better question if you did some digging and found the history.  Which one came first?

I always thought NASM was much more sensible, with memory refs always using `[addr]`, and not trying to infer operand size from the declarations of symbols.  I think NASM should have allowed `mov reg, OFFSET symbol`, so you could unambiguously write something that would assemble to `mov r32, imm32` regardless of which assembler you were using (just like you can always use `[mem]` for MASM.)  Although you can define `OFFSET` as a macro that expands to the empty string.

AT&T syntax came from Unix using AT&T syntax for the RISC architectures that Unix typically ran on.  GNU gcc (or whoever invented AT&T syntax for x86) followed that tradition.  See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194571/224132) to a question about why AT&T syntax is so weird (more or less).

Comment: Don't you prefer yasm? If so, then why? Second question. You wrote "for the RISC architectures that Unix typically ran on". I was not aware of this. Wasn't UNIX and C were primarily developed on a PDP11. Is that RISC? Did it have a FLAGS register? If it did not have a FLAGS register that could explain why C can't handle `adc`.

Comment: @Zboson: I went for yasm based on x264/x265's choice.  It still uses NASM syntax.  I haven't compared yasm vs. nasm in detail.  I think yasm's macro facilities are slightly different, but I haven't ended up writing large volumes of code in asm and needing macros.  And yes, Unix and C started on PDP11.  [It's *not* a RISC machine, though, and it does have a carry flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture).  I think I've read that it's assembly syntax is AT&T-style, and where they originally got the idea.

Comment: Yasm can do AT&T and Intel syntax (I think). NASM only does Intel syntax. I think Yasm used to handle multi-byte NOPS better but I'm not sure that's true anymore. Those are the only differences I am aware of.

Comment: @Zboson: That's correct that YASM has an AT&T mode.  It defaults to using long NOPs.  I read once recently that NASM defaults to short NOPs, unless you use a directive to change that.