# Is there a subset of assembler language which is platform-independent?

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I've recently come across the `asm` reserved word in C. I want to exploit it to avoid some C semantic rules: in particular I would like to modify a variable out of a function:

```
int a = 5;
asm("asm code to change a from 5 to, like, 6")

int main() {
    printf("a equal to %d\n", a);
}
```

Now, from my computer science course I know that assembly is platform dependent, so its use should be very limited. However, I've seen some recurrent instructions, like MOV or ADD.

My questions are:

1. Although assembly is globally platform dependent, is there a subset of it that is understood by all assembler? I mean, if I were to write `asm("MOV something somethingelse")` and assuming MOV is inside this hypothetical subset, would the code be correct regardless of the platform?
2. If that platform independent subset exists indeed, can someone link it?
3. If there is no platform-independent subset, which are the most common assembler syntaxes?

Comment: 1) no. 3) question makes no sense. PS: your example doesn't work because your asm is never going to be executed if it's not part of control flow.

Comment: "I want to exploit it to avoid some C semantic rules" - That's not possible! If you use assembly, there are no C semantic rules. In C you have to pay heed to them! What you try looks like an XY problem and a very hackish approach. Note: this is **not** a compliment! And the snippets don't make any sense at all. You cannot have statements outside a block and `asm` **is** a statement.

Comment: Now you should ask the real question. What are you trying to do which s not possible by using the "C semantic rules"?

Comment: To some extend `C` *is* portable assembly language. Pointers are what you use to modify the contents of a variable like you want to do.

Comment: Why don't you just do it in C? `asm` is non-standard btw

Comment: By the way -- I don't think that it is a dumb question (even if the answer is negative). It is a reasonable enough thing to ask and has probably occurred to other programmers (especially those new to assembly language programming). I don't think that your question deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: Well, in some parallel universe there might be some Asm standard regulating the instruction sets supported by all complying architectures. But we are not there.

Comment: How are you going to write code for one processor, and expect it to work on another, which does not have the equivalent instruction, or not enough registers?

Comment: @WeatherVane Theoretically, in the universe mentioned above, the standard would say "Any architecture has to have at least X general purpose registers, and such and such instructions to manipulate them".

Comment: `C` is exactly that, the main goal for `C` was to replace assembler which is Processor-dependent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly language standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065026/assembly-language-standard)

Comment: "I would like to modify a variable out of a function" - And just when do you expect that modification to occur?

Comment: As has already been pointed out, there is no such thing as a universal, platform-independent assembly language because assembly language is "bare metal", translates directly to machine code, and is therefore different for each microprocessor design. However, it is worse than that. Even if there *was* a universal assembly language, there isn't a universal  syntax for including inline assembly in C. Different compilers implement the `asm` statement differently, so you'd need to clutter your code with a bunch of `#ifdef`s to check which compiler you were on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) Although assembly is globally platform dependent, is there a subset
>   of it that is understood by all assembler? I mean, if I were to write
>   asm("MOV something somethingelse") and assuming MOV is inside this
>   hypothetical subset, would the code be correct regardless of the
>   platform?

Nope. While all versions of assembly language might have a command like MOV, syntax would be different, registers would be different, and when it was assembled into machine language, the actual binary code representing that instruction would probably be different.

Think of it this way - a platform-independent subset would have to assemble down to the exact same set of bits, which each computer would have to interpret the same, (or assemblers would have to be written for all different architectures for the same assembly language). If this was the case, platform independence would be a rather trivial task.

> 2) If that platform independent subset exists indeed, can someone link
>   it?

It doesn't, so nope.

> 3) If there is no platform-independent subset, which are the most
>   common assembler syntaxes?

MASM, NASM, and GAS (especially for ARM architectures)

Comment: 1) There are no common keywords for all assemblies. Not even `MOV`. 3) I would argue that today the ARM is even more common than X86.

Comment: In "a platform-independent subset would have to assemble down to the exact same set of bits, which each computer would have to interpret the same" I think you are confusing instruction sets with mnemonics. You could *write* a set of assemblers that share mnemonics, but by convention many processors' assemblers do not have the `MOV` instruction you cite.

Comment: You're not! Hence the "which each computer would have to interpret the same" I guess it could be more explicit on how instructions from two architectures simply can't by interpreted the same.

Comment: ARM is not a syntax anymore than x86 or mips is.  GAS would have made more sense there.

Comment: gas supports way more targets that just arm but perhaps I am aligned in where you may be thinking there are so many more arm processors than x86 and gnu is heavily used for those that gnu assembler for arm is up there in the top so many percent if it were possible to measure.

Comment: I feel my question was too much ignorant. I was curious to know at what extent assembly was not standardized and from your answers it feels like not standardized at all. I hoped at least some mnemonics were recurrent, but apparently this is not the case. So, if a program were to use `asm` reserved word, should I always expect to be platform-dependent (from the C99 standard, I know `asm` is compiler-implementation dependent)?

Comment: Your question was fine! Yes I'd say you should assume the code to be platform-dependent. Now if you had a really strong idea of who would be using the code (ie what computer would be executing it), and it was all the same kind of computers, maybe you'd be able to slip in some asm without causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

If and how you insert assembly language into C is very much compiler specific, so first and foremost you lose any portability there.  Second, assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that parses it, x86 has several to dozens of assembly languages for the same machine code.  And no there is no such notion as anything common across assembly languages as a result.  Even when you use inline assembly what does linking have to do with it, if you wanted to link then make an object, not inline.  For x86 the most popular are probably as answered already nasm, masm and gnu assembler, just look at the stackoverflow tags I think the hits are in that order.

Lastly you cant change the C language with inline assembly language, that is not how that works.

Comment: would it be possible to make your own assembler that supports multiple targets and create at least a few common syntax instructions across the targets, yep absolutely, not just nop which is pretty close to one that is common now.

Comment: I've thought about the `asm`: even if, by absurd, I could have written a platform-independent assembly code, when that code is supposed to be executed? Like you and others said, that is just not how this works. Thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: inline assembly is specific to the C compiler as to how it works, generally those instructions are inserted right where you put them, but there are rules as you can be and are stomping on resources the compiler is using, so in addition to just doing assembly language you have to tell the compier, i am using register r5 and r3, and want the variable xyz from C, so please help me with that.  and in addition to the specific compiler inline assembly the assembly language there is this additional stuff that is compiler specific.